# How to specify source files location when debugging?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have DLL and PDB files, and source code files. But I can't put source code to the same location as specified in PDBs. Is there any way to enforce VS to look for source files in a manually specified location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case, start with Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, General, ensure "Always show solution" is ticked.

In the Solution Explorer window, right-click the solution (top), Properties, Common Properties.  Add directories to Debug Source Files.